# How to integrate problem

Tags: calculus

I've tried u substitution and partial fraction doesn't seem to work either.

$\int \frac{1}{x^2+3}$

Can I take $\int \frac{1}{x^2+\sqrt(3)^2}$ in order to use $x=a\tan\theta$

Answer (score 1):

We are asked to evaluate $ \int \frac{1}{x^2+3}dx$. We need to know $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx= \arctan(x)+C$ to answer this question.

We need to modify the denominator $x^2+3$. Note $x^2+3 = 3(\frac{x^2}{3}+1)$. So we have

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2+3}dx = \int \frac{1}{3(\frac{x^2}{3}+1)}dx = \frac{1}{3} \int \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{3}+1}dx  $$

Now we want to make use of substitution rule. In doing so, we want $u^2 = \frac{x^2}{3}$, which means we can let $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt 3}$. After a bit of algebra you can conclude

$$ \int \frac{1}{x^2+3}dx = \frac{\sqrt 3}{3} \arctan( \frac{\sqrt 3 \ x}{3}) + C $$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\dfrac{1}{x^2+3}dx$$
Apply substitution $x=\sqrt3u$
$$\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3(u^2+1}du=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\int\dfrac{1}{u^2+1}du=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan (u)$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt3}\arctan\left(\dfrac{x}{\sqrt3}\right)+C$$

Answer (score 0):

It's an arctan integral so substitute that

Comment: how exactly do I do that

Comment: $\tan u = x/\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Check the edit I made

Comment: Yeah that will work